# Prove that lim sup $|B(n)| = \infty$ almost surely, where $B(n)$ is standard Brownian motion.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Okay, I have cleared up some of my proof. Sorry for confusion (it was first time to be in this StackExchange, to make an excuse).

HINT(given): Use the independent increments property of brownian motion and continuity property.

What I want to do is to show that probability of having each random moment of Brownian motion smaller than $\epsilon$ is zero.

$P(\sup (B(t_2) - B(t_1) < \epsilon), sup (B(t_3) - B(t_2)) < \epsilon, ..., ) = \prod P (sup (B(t_i ) - B(t_i-1)) < \epsilon), $

by independent increment property.

I think I can use the continuity property to show that the product of such is equal to zero, and then probability of having each Brownian smaller than $\epsilon$ is zero. Thus, $\limsup \left| B(n) \right| = \infty.$

I want to know:

> i) Am I on the right track?
>
> ii) How can I move to the rest of the proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't tell you where your proof is too informal unless you include the actual proof in your question... for all we know it might be correct

Comment: Can you please proofread your question and explain the notation?  As written the claim appears to be something that is definitely false.  You should also explain your solution more carefully, as I can't understand it at all from what you wrote.

Comment: Yes, it is equality not inequality. Sorry. I edited it.

Comment: Also, the solution, I found out just now is just totally nonsense. Not worthy to even mention it. I thought each X_i will have 1 maximum. Sorry.